# Neovim: run cmd on write

Tags: neovim, terminal, vim-windows

I've got a file open in Neovim like so:

```
neovim test.rb
```

And a split open like so:

```
:split ruby test.rb
```

How can I rerun the split command each time I write a save in the original window?

**Update**

I've updated the question to make it clearer, sorry about that. I want to edit in one buffer then run the changes in the terminal split.

Comment: As is, im not sure what the splitting does (other than appear to open a new file with the name `cat test.txt`)—do you want to open several splits, close the old one and open a new one, ...? You’re question is a bit unclear.

Comment: (Also, welcome to [vi.se] :)

Comment: Thanks! The `cat` was just an example, any shell command would suffice.

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have a guess at an answer, but the question isnt clear. Are you trying to run the cat command? Your current code wont do that

Comment: Sorry all, I've updated the question.

Comment: Still a bit unclear: the given command (`:split ruby file.rb`) doesn't deal with a terminal split. So, you want to, on save, run a given command? Does it have to be in a terminal, or do you just care about the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you might like to look into any of the many plugins that incorporate a REPL into Vim ([vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime.git) is the one I use). They don't do *exactly* what you're asking, but they do something very similar and are far more flexible.

If you want your exact behaviour, though, then here's a proof of concept that shows how you can implement it:

```
augroup RunCommandOnWrite
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePost test.rb call RunCommand()
augroup END

function! RunCommand() abort
  " Find terminal
  windo if &buftype == "terminal" | let s:terminal = bufnr('%') | endif

  " Type in command
  call term_sendkeys(s:terminal, "ruby test.rb\<CR>")
endfunction
```

It works by setting up an [`autocommand`](https://www.vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocommand) to run every time that you save a file named `test.rb`.

The autocommand calls a function that finds a visible terminal buffer and then sends the keystrokes `ruby test.rb<Enter>` to them to run your command.

There is a lot you can/should do to make this more robust, if you're intending to use it. Feel free to ask if you need any tips on how to do so.

In order to use it, you need to open your terminal by typing [`:terminal`](https://www.vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#:terminal) (the [`:split`](https://www.vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#:split) command you included in your question does *not* run a command or open a terminal) and then return to your ruby file by typing <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>.

It's actually unclear from your question whether you need a terminal or a split window at all. If your goal is literally just to run a shell command whenever you save a file, all you need is the following:

```
augroup RunCommandOnWrite
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePost test.rb !ruby test.rb
augroup END
```

Instead of running a function, this directly invokes the command `ruby test.rb` by using `:!`. See [`:help :!cmd`](https://www.vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:!cmd) for more details.

Comment: I find the Clam plugin helpful for slightly less interactive versions of this

Comment: This is amazingly helpful, thanks so much!